# SVN Checkout using NetBeans with Ignoring library and .svn files

Tags: svn, netbeans, svn-checkout

I have my project uploaded in svn server with some specific URL.

Now I am using netbeans 6.8 integration of subversion by accessing Team -> Subversion -> Checkout option.

But in this scenario, my whole project including library as well as some .svn (hidden) files are also checking out into the server, which is affecting my grails project.

So, ultimately my requirement is to manage an svn in such a way that when anyone checking out the project in netbeans, then they should not get the library files as well as .svn (hidden) files in their project.

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you do a svn checkout, you get metadata stored in hidden .svn folders.  You can get the code without the data by using 'export' instead of 'checkout', but without the metadata you won't be able to commit, revert, or do most other Subversion operations.  From your description I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to deploy code from a Subversion repo onto a server then the drawbacks of 'export' shouldn't cause any problems.  Is this indeed what you are trying to do?

Regarding your request to ignore libs, you can set your local client to ignore certain files or folders, but there may not be an easy way to force everyone accessing your repo to ignore the libs.  Can you provide any details about how your repo is laid out and how these libs are stored in relation to everything else?